# php's range function behavior

Tags: php

[PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)'s documentation on the `range` function is a little lacking. These functions produce unexpected (to me anyways) results when given character ranges.

`$m = range('A','z');
print_r($m);
$m = range('~','"');
print_r($m);`

I'm looking for a reference that might explicitly define its behavior.

Comment: What are the results its outputting? What are your expected results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that range treats its arguments like integers, and if you give it a single character it will convert it to its [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) character code.

In the first case, you're getting all characters between character 'A' (integer 65) and character 'z' (integer 122). This is expected behavior for those of us coming from a C (or C-like language) background.

This is one of the rare cases where PHP converts single characters to their ASCII codes rather than parsing the string as integer the way it does normally. Most of the PHP documentation is better at telling you when to expect this. [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) for example, notes:

> **Needle**
>
> > If needle is not a string, it is converted to an integer and applied as the ordinal value of a character.

The documentation for [range](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) is strangely quiet about it.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. The other answers are helpful, but yours best answers my question. My apologies to the other responders, my question was vague. My implied question was "where is the documentation" and I interpret meagar's answer as "there is none". Also, I suppose didn't label my link correctly, but that range doc is the address I was pointing at.  I verified your definition using: header('Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
print_r (range(chr(0),chr(255)));

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
foreach (range('A','z') as $c)
  echo $c."\n";
```

to be equivalent to:

```
for ($i = ord('A'); $i <= ord('z'); ++$i)
  echo chr($i)."\n";
```

Likewise, your second example is equivalent to (since `ord('~')` > `ord('"')`):

```
for ($i = ord('~'); $i >= ord('"'); --$i)
  echo chr($i)."\n";
```

It's not well documented, but that's how it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

that is because " is a lower character than ~  try

m = range('A','z'); print_r($m);

$m = range('z','A'); print_r($m);

the characters are pulled by their chr (ASCII Table) values:

http://www.asciitable.com/

the array is returned in the directional order of the 2 parameters.